# Filter applying to only one model with Tire and ElasticSearch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have several models indexed with elasticsearch and one of them has an association that needs to be filtered, but if I add something like this into the `search` method

```
  search.filter :range, 'sessions.starts_on' => {:gte => start_date,
                                                 :lte => ends_on}
```

then all the models are filtered out because they don't have such an association `sessions`.

So is there a way to apply filter to only one model?

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: are you using AciveRecord? and have you considered customizing the to_json index method for this?

Comment: yes for ActiveRecord. And customizing index - how exactly? to have these 'sessions.starts_on' returning what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a module for tire index specifically related to that model and include it in the model. As sessions is only association with the model its reference will be there in document which is going to elasticsearch. You have to merge the sessions document in your model document like this as we passed the json of document to elasticsearch in tire index module

```
def to_model_json
    self.document.merge({"sessions" => sessions.as_json}).to_json
end
```

this method is passing a document in json to elasticsearch through tire which will be having their sessions merged in the document.

in tire index module give a index name which you can pass in the tire search object to run the filter queries

Now create a tire search object

```
search_object = Tire::Search::Search::new(Model.index_name, other attributes)
```

you can check other attributes which you can pass from https://github.com/karmi/tire

then run your search method like this it will give the desired result

```
 search_object.filter :range, 'sessions.starts_on' => {:gte => start_date,
                                                  :lte => ends_on}
```